# SwiftUI modal sheet with Form: wrong left/right padding after device rotation

Tags: swift, xcode, forms, swiftui

When opening a modal sheet including a Form and then rotating the device to landscape mode and back to portrait mode, everything behaves normal. However, if the modal sheet gets opened in landscape mode and then rotated to portrait mode, the padding on the left and the right not as expected. I think it's a bug in SwiftUI. Is there a workaround?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var modalDisplayed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.modalDisplayed = true }) {
            Text("Show Modal")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalDisplayed) {
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Section")){
                    
                    Text("This is a test.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How it should look:
[image]

How it looks if the modal sheet was opened in landscape and then rotated to portrait:

[image]

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: Problem is that the app should run on iOS 13... Is there a way to manually set the borders?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 as well. Is this really that code?

Comment: It's not working fine for me with Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5.

Comment: So it's a bug in Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5? I currently do not have access to Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4...

Answer (score 0):

`.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` fixed this for me. (Using Xcode 11.5 / iOS 13.5)

[image][image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var modalDisplayed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.modalDisplayed = true }) {
            Text("Show Modal")
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$modalDisplayed) {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Section")){
                    Text("This is a test.")
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad news: Using Xcode 12 / iOS 14 however, with and without `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` - both have padding in landscape mode. Hence this is somehow nondeterministic?

Comment: Also, that doesn't work for me. I ran your code but the issue still persists

Comment: As far as I can tell, it works on almost all devices except on the iPhone X/XS/11 Pro. Weird.

Comment: How is that possible? I even tried it on two macs... Really strange.

Comment: I tested it with iOS 13.6 and iOS 14. For me, your solution does not work on iOS 13.6. However, the bug does not occur on iOS 14. Guess I have to wait then ... :/